# pandas: most elegant way to pivot table on pattern in name of columns

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Given the following DataFrame:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
  'x': [0, 1],
  'y': [0, 1],
  'a_idx': [0, 1],
  'a_val': [2, 3],
  'b_idx': [4, 5],
  'b_val': [6, 7],
})
```

What is the cleanest way to pivot the DataFrame based on the prefix of the idx and val columns if you have an indeterminate amount of unique prefixes (a, b, ... n), so as to obtain the following DataFrame?

```
pd.DataFrame({
  'x': [0, 1, 0, 1],
  'y': [0, 1, 0, 1],
  'key': ['a','a','b','b'],
  'idx': [0, 1, 4, 5],
  'val': [2, 3, 6, 7]
})
```

I am not very knowledgeable in pandas, so my easiest solution was to go earlier in the data generation process and generate a subset of the result DataFrame for each prefix in SQL, and then concat the result sets into a final DataFrame. I'm curious however if there is a simple way to do this using the API of pandas.DataFrame. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `wide_to_long` with extras:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df,stubnames=['a','b'],
                i=['x','y'],
                j='key',
                sep='_',
                suffix='\\w+'
               )
   .unstack('key').stack(level=0).reset_index()
)
```

Or manually with `melt`:

```
out = df.melt(['x', 'y'])
out = (out.join(out['variable'].str.split('_', expand=True))
       .rename(columns={0: 'key'})
       .pivot_table(index=['x', 'y', 'key'], columns=[1], values='value')
       .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
key  x  y level_2  idx  val
0    0  0       a    0    2
1    0  0       b    4    6
2    1  1       a    1    3
3    1  1       b    5    7
```

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang! 
I prefer the `wide_to_long` approach as it is more readable. Great to know! :)